# Select rows from a DataFrame based on multiple values in a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is not a repetitive question, yet similar to

> [Select rows from a DataFrame based on values in a column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas)

In that answer up in the previous link it is only based on one criteria what if I have more than one criteria.

I would like to select many rows in a column not only one based on particular values. For the sake of argument consider the DataFrame from the World Bank

```
import pandas.io.wb as wb
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df2= wb.get_indicators()
```

The way I select a certian value is as so

```
df2.loc[df2['id'] == 'SP.POP.TOTL']
```

and

```
df2.loc[df2['id'] == 'NY.GNP.PCAP.CD']
```

How may I select both in one new dataframe or say 3 or 4? such that the rows are:

```
'SP.POP.TOTL'
'NY.GNP.PCAP.CD'
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: How does this differ from the answer to the question you linked, which gives an `isin` example in its second sentence?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

you may use [.isin()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html):

```
In [28]: df2[df2['id'].isin(['SP.POP.TOTL','NY.GNP.PCAP.CD'])]
Out[28]:
                  id                                        name  \
7478  NY.GNP.PCAP.CD  GNI per capita, Atlas method (current US$)
9568     SP.POP.TOTL                           Population, total

                            source  \
7478  World Development Indicators
9568  World Development Indicators

                                             sourceNote  \
7478  GNI per capita (formerly GNP per capita) is th...
9568  Total population is based on the de facto defi...

                                     sourceOrganization  \
7478  b'World Bank national accounts data, and OECD ...
9568  b'(1) United Nations Population Division. Worl...

                                 topics
7478  Economy & Growth ; Climate Change
9568           Health  ; Climate Change
```